# Refactoring to Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka

I am working on a small project using SpringBoot to retrieve data from Kafka and pass it to third party supplier. My project is not dependent upon our other micro-services.

I am wondering if there would be any performance improvement if refactored to Kotlin or if it is purely for readability?

Comment: The main advantage of Kotlin is improved expressiveness and "time to market"; not necessarily runtime performance. From that point of view, your question doesnt really fit this community.

Comment: I don't think that Kotlin can really cut on any expenses on time performance as its resources are fixed. So, eventhough stackoverflow might not suit that type of question, readabiltity is the answer to your question.

Comment: it all compiles down to java bytecode anyway so it shouldn't be any performance improvements.

Comment: Well yeah if you have a recursive method and you use `tailrec` keyword for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation of Kotlin seems slower: https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/kotlin-vs-java-compilation-speed-e6c174b39b5d

Other than that it is bytecode in both places. So the only difference is if there are faster implementations of functions in Kotlin. (probably not).

However if you can make more readable code (subjective) in Kotlin, then you have a higher chance of finding places to optimize.

TLDR: do not port language for performance reasons in the language alone.

Comment: But that evaluation is from 2 years ago. Both Gradle and Kotlin have made many improvements, so I'd be surprised if there's much difference anymore.

I certainly wouldn't discount Kotlin even if it's a bit slower, as the compiler does more, and I find the language helps nudge devs in the right direction more often than not.

Really like static analysis directly as part of build using Detekt as opposed to after fact like Sonarqube.

Answer (score 0):

Java is closer to the way JVM works than Kotlin (methods can't look like field accesses, you can better see where primitives are used compared to classes, etc.). Any performance differences when trying to write equivalent code (i.e. without algorithmic improvements) are likely to be the other way around. But they are also likely to be trivial, especially when considered as a part of the complete application.

Comment: Hmm so use Kotlin if I think another abstraction layer would be useful?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. Use it for readability and productivity. Where performance is concerned, you _can_ still do pretty much everything you do in Java in Kotlin, you just need to understand how it works.